# How does the Control Weather spell interact with the Dispel Magic spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

If a spell has an area of effect with a radius of miles, like Control Weather, or Mirage Arcane, is there anything stopping a level 5 mage, hiding somewhere within the area, from dispelling the terrible storm cast by the archmage?

It feels like these massive spells are extremely vulnerable since, at most, they’d need to beat a 19 on an ability check. Surely it’d make for a very anticlimactic fight if the mega-storm conjured by the BBEG was dispelled by a couple of apprentice mages.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As *control weather* and *mirage arcane* are two very different spells, I'd probably edit out the mention of the latter and ask about its interaction with *dispel magic* separately.

Answer (score 12):

### Dispel Magic can be used to dispel Control Weather

*Control Weather* causes a magical effect with a 5 mile radius, centered on self. A successful cast of *Dispel Magic* from within 120 feet of that area ends the spell, as you’d expect.

Some notes based on your question description however:

If you wanted to dispel it, you’d have to know the weather is magical, you’d need to have *Dispel Magic* known/prepared (depending on your class) and a 3rd level spell slot available, and then pass DC 18/19 so check to dispel it (pure spellcasting ability check, so a caster with a 20 in their spellcasting ability would still need 2-3 tries on average, even if they’re a bard unless it’s a relatively high level bard). Now all of these individually aren’t extremely high barriers, but they’re still there.

Even if you do end the spell, this doesn’t immediately stop the weather conditions caused by *Control Weather*, rather the spell description specifies:

> When the spell ends, the weather gradually returns to normal.

So if you did dispel the spell, the caster would be very annoyed but the immediate threat caused by any existing storm or the like wouldn’t disappear instantly. (And if the weather wasn’t bad enough to be a problem already, how’d you even guess it’s a magical effect or bother with dispelling it?). A sufficiently powerful caster could simply resume casting the spell (if they have more castings/spell slots available). And of course, considering how long this spell needs to take effect no competent caster would bother with it if they weren’t relatively sure they’d not get interrupted.

Comment: Knowing the weather is magical is the big step here. And you can't even use *detect magic* because that works on only objects and creatures.

Comment: This is what I originally thought, but the other answers raise an interesting concept: YOU are the one who gains powers, the caster can change the weather, that’s essentially the spell. So perhaps the magic isn’t in the 5mile radius area, but it’s in you, and thus you’d have to dispel the caster?

Comment: @Nicolas I think that’s a _plausible_ reading, but I’m not convinced it’s the right one based on the wording. I think that if when it rains on you because magic was used to make it rain, saying that the magics effect don’t extend to where you are because the person controlling the weather is somewhere else would be a bit of a stretch of the english language.

Comment: Here's a question discussing dispelling a self range spell when not targeting the caster, like your answer here: "[Does Dispel Magic work on Tiny Hut](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144407)"

Comment: @Cubic, I think you’ve found the heart of the problem: is the weather (created by control weather) a magical effect? Clearly the sphere from Leomund’s Tiny Hut is a magical effect, but with weather it feels different.

Comment: I do think I’ve found a satisfying solution to the issue of easy dispel: fly more than 5 miles up, so now enemy casters can’t touch you. If you want to affect precipitation, then it’s the clouds that must change, so you could make it rain down bellow by affecting the atmosphere above. Even better: if it’s hot in the city, you could create a tornado by generating cold air and wind above.

Comment: @Nicolas Honestly if all you want is a non-dispellable _Control Weather_ nothing is stopping you from just making one up. Give the caster a magic item that continuously does a _Control Weather_ like effect, something of the sort. Would be a legendary tier item of course, but that seems to be the sort of powerlevel you’re going for anyway.

Comment: @Cubic, yeah I suppose that if you’re on that power level, you might as well enslave something like an Elder Tempest or something like that. It’s sad to think that a few apprentices could ruin your massive spell, but it seems to be RAI.

Comment: @Nicolas Also remember that NPCs don't need to follow the rules for PCs. If you want your BBEG to do something like this, they can. It can be something as simple as a lair action.