# How does the Resilient Sphere spell interact with the Antimagic Field spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, antimagic-field

[*Resilient sphere's*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/resilient-sphere) description states that

> Nothing--not physical objects, energy, or other spell effects--can pass through the barrier, in or out

While [*antimagic field's*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) description negates any magical effects within the field (-sphere).

The relevant sections of the *antimagic field* description are:

1. > Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.
2. > **Areas of Magic.** The area of another spell or magical effect, such as *fireball*, can't extend into the sphere. If the sphere overlaps an area of magic, the part of the area that is covered by the sphere is suppressed. For example, the flames created by a *wall of fire* are suppressed within the sphere, creating a gap in the wall if the overlap is large enough.

**Which would win if the areas of effect overlapped?** Both say "effects cannot protrude", but *antimagic field* specifically cancels any spell effect.

1. What if the *resilient sphere* is already cast and another caster casts *antimagic field* nearby?
2. What if the *antimagic field* is already cast and another caster casts *resilient sphere* nearby?
3. What if the caster casts *resilient sphere*, then *antimagic field*?
4. What if the caster casts *antimagic field*, then *resilient sphere*?
5. What if someone within *resilient sphere* moved into *antimagic field*?
6. What if the creature targeted by *resilient sphere* moved into *antimagic field*? Are both spheres suppressed?

Logically, the *antimagic field* should cancel the sphere in all scenarios, but I'm looking for more RAW answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antimagic field vs 9th-level globe of invulnerability: who wins?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128354/antimagic-field-vs-9th-level-globe-of-invulnerability-who-wins) (I know the wording in *Globe of Invulnerability* isn't identical, but I believe the same logic applies.)

Comment: @RyanThompson AFAIR having the same answer does not make Qs dupes.

Comment: I’m sorry that I didn’t see the answers that QuantumDM and Gandalfmeansme had posted on the other question first. I would have referenced them and added my own bit about how I think it justifies the idea that AF may have no spell effects (mechanistically speaking).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Antimagic Field pretty much trumps all

I think the best way to understand Antimagic Field is to think of it in terms of a  vacuum. Calling it a field can be misleading because we may think it implies that something is there actively doing something (suppressing magic). But it's actually a void, a black hole, an area...

> ...divorced from the magical energy that suffuses the multiverse.

In game terms the area has no spell effects. Yes, it is a spell and the caster is doing magic, but the resultant area, devoid of magic and all, presents no spell effects to be interacted with. As such, it bypasses anything that claims protection from spell effects.

My best support for this is that Dispel Magic, which targets creatures, objects, and magical effects, has no effect on Antimagic Field. And that one Antimagic Field doesn't negate a second (which itself also affects spells and magical effects).

As for Resilient Sphere, I agree that logically Antimagic Field should cancel it and hopefully this will satisfy why. Simply put, nothing is actually passing through the barrier. There isn't anything to the Antimagic Field to pass through the barrier. As the areas overlap, the magic that supports the existence of the Resilient Sphere is pulled out from under it. Perhaps that magic is turned 90-degrees to our plane of existence or ported to some demiplane, but regardless, it's just gone. Any portion of the Sphere affected would be suppressed only to return as the overlap diminishes.

Comment: Ported to some random plane is a great story hook when the residents of said plane realise who has caused all their random happenings!

Answer (score 4):

### The barrier of *Resilient Sphere* cannot extend into an *Antimagic Field*

Spell effects can't pass through the barrier of a *Resilient Sphere* spell, but that doesn't matter, because *Antimagic Field* suppresses the barrier entirely. Once the barrier is suppressed, there's nothing to block the *Antimagic Field* from extending into or out of the area of the *Resilient Sphere* spell. So no matter how you cause the two spells to overlap, *Antimagic Field* always suppresses the barrier of *Resilient Sphere* and extends unimpeded through the area where the barrier would be. It never passes through the barrier, because the barrier doesn't exist within the field. Just as in the case of [*Antimagic Field* vs. *Globe of Invulnerability*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128354/antimagic-field-vs-9th-level-globe-of-invulnerability-who-wins), ***Resilient Sphere* protects its interior from spell effects, but it doesn't protect *itself*, so *Antimagic Field* punches right through it.**